# LibreOffice crashes after installing AMDGPU-PRO drivers

Tags: drivers, libreoffice, crash, amdgpu-pro

I installed the AMDGPU-PRO drivers on my fresh Ubuntu install (driver version 17.40-492261), and everything was working fine for a while. Then I noticed that I couldn't open LibreOffice applications at all - the LibreOffice splash screen would appear with the progress bar, but would then crash and "Sorry, Ubuntu 16.04 has experienced an internal error" would appear.

Here's some info from the crash dialog:

> ExecutablePath: /usr/lib/libreoffice/program/soffice.bin
>
> ProblemType: Crash
>
> Title: soffice.bin crashed with SIGSEGV
>
> StacktraceTop: A bunch of lines, all with
>   /opt/amdgpu-pro/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libamdocl64.so
>
> UpgradeStatus: No upgrade log present (probably fresh install)

What can I do to fix this, other than uninstalling the AMDGPU-PRO drivers? Please let me know if I can provide any further information.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

cd /opt/amdgpu-pro/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/

mv libamdocl64.so libamdocl64.so.bak

ln -s libamdocl12cl64.so libamdocl64.so

It worked for me, I'm Running Linux Mint 18.3 with kernel 4.10 and amdgpu-pro 17.30

Regards
hotschi